# mysql error during application installaton

Tags: mysql, database

I need your help on the following issue. I'm installing a software (which uses mysql) and it fetches me the following error during installation:

I install the software, during install it says to name the project, I input 'drilling' as name, the process goes on and after a whilee I get:

"Create project failed: Setup was unable to create the trusted drilling account for localhost\drilling" (Note: 'drilling' is the project name)

When I press OK, the installation goes on and finishes. After running the app it says:
"Setup the DB connecton first".

I go to options and there are 2 options: Local DB and Network Server. When I choose Local DB it says Can't find any suitable DB in your local machine! When I choose Network Server it allows me to choose the project DRILLING and when I press Test Connection it says "Test connection not successful".

Can you help me with this problem?

I understand that my explanation might look like very messy, but I did my best..

Comment: mysql not setup in your local pc maybe

Comment: how can I set it up?

Comment: You may or may not need to install MySQL separately depending on the software - you'll have to check the installation instructions. You could try running the installation as administrator if you haven't already. Although [so] is for questions directly related to programming, which this doesn't seem to be. Your best bet will probably be to try to contact whomever developed the software you're trying to install (or find a forum dedicated to it, and make sure you follow the installation instructions to the letter before that).